# How to calculate an unknown total when you know the amount of the percent

Tags: php

how to calculate an unknown total when you know the amount of the percent

270 is 90% of the total amount how I can calculate the the total amount

Basically I have 2 values to calculate the unknown total

one is percent and another is amount but the amount is already discounted 10%

suppose an item having 300

discount applied on it is 10%

I get discounted value that is 270 but I want to show the discount amount of total price that 300

So how I can formulate the actual discount price

So the result should be 30

Comment: Reverse the calculation? How would you go from 300 - 10% to 270? Just reverse that

Comment: I don't have amount 300, I just have 270 and 10%. Means the amount I got is already discounted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is fundementally a question about basic Mathematics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
$val = 270;
$percentage = 10;
$total = $val * 100 /(100 - $percentage);
$discount = $total - $val;
echo 'Total = '.$total; // Total = 300
echo 'Discount = '.$discount; // Discount = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$priceAfterDiscount = 1000;
$discountPercentage = 10;
$price = $priceAfterDiscount / ((100 - $discountPercentage) / 100);
$totalDiscount = $price * ($discountPercentage / 100);

echo number_format((float)$totalDiscount, 2, '.', ''); // 30.00
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.